# How to write an image file from python to C++ using PyCxx

Tags: python, c++, pycxx

I would like to be able to write an image from Python (or any binary file for that matter) to C++, using PyCxx and have the C++ layer write that to a file. I can't find any binary type in PyCXX that would enable this - the closest thing is Py::Bytes seems to be based on 'char' type.

Any ideas/suggestions?

Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Read about [Extending and Embedding the Python interpreter](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/index.html)

Comment: I am restricted to using PyCxx library though. That is the current interface between C++ and python that I have.

Comment: Then read the documentation of `PyCxx`. If it is open source, study also its source code